# How to alphabetically sort two dimensional array in java

Tags: java, arrays, sorting

Lets say i have a two dimensional array:

```
String [][] arr = {
{"bob","one"},
{"jack","two"},
{"adam","three"}
};
```

i would like to sort alphabetically according to column 0
so adam would be first the bob the jack - and it (or new array) will look like so:

```
{"adam","three"}
{"bob","one"},
{"jack","two"},
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? **EDIT** Never mind, SO registers a 2 second difference XD

Comment: Nice comment @Arc676 XD

Comment: So far i have tried staring at the problem and searching on stackoverflow..
now i will read about Comparators- thanks Mihir!

Comment: you should accept mihir's answer if you think it helped you to show appreciation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Comparator;


public class demo_sort {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        final String[][] data = new String[][] {
                new String[] {"bob","one"},
                new String[] {"jack","two"},
                new String[] {"adam","three"}
                };

        Arrays.sort(data, new Comparator<String[]>() {
            @Override
            public int compare(final String[] entry1, final String[] entry2) {
                final String time1 = entry1[0];
                final String time2 = entry2[0];
                return time1.compareTo(time2);
            }
        });

        for (final String[] s : data) {
            System.out.println(s[0] + " " + s[1]);
        }

    }

}
```

**output**

adam three
bob one
jack two